# Sum of product: can we vectorize the following in C++? (using Eigen or other libraries)

Tags: c++, optimization, matrix, vectorization, eigen

**UPDATE:** the (sparse) three-dimensional matrix `v` in my question below is **symmetric**: `v(i1,i2,i3) = v(j1,j2,j3)` where `(j1,j2,j3)` is any of the 6 permutations of `(i1,i2,i3)`, i.e.

`v(i1,i2,i3) = v(i1,i3,i2) = v(i2,i3,i1) = v(i2,i1,i3) = v(i3,i1,i2) = v(i3,i2,i1)`.

Moreover, `v(i1,i2,i3) != 0` only when `i1 != i2 && i1 != i3 && i2 != i3`.

E.g. `v(i,i,j) = 0`, `v(i, k, k) = 0`, `v(k, j, k) = 0`, etc...

I thought that with this additional information, I could already get a significant speed-up by doing the following:

- Remark: `v` contains duplicate values (a triplet `(i,j,k)` has 6 permutations, and the values of `v` for these 6 are the same).
- So I defined a more compact matrix `u`that contains only non-duplicates of `v`. The indices of `u` are `(i1,i2,i3)` where `i1 < i2 < i3`. The length of `u` is equal to the length of `v` divided by 6.
- I computed the sum by iterating over the new value vector and the new index vectors.

With this, I only got a little speed-up. I realized that instead of iterating `N` times doing a multiplication each time, I iterated `N/6` times doing 6 multiplications each time, and that's pretty much the same as before :(

Hope somebody could come up with a better solution.

--- (Original question) ---

In my program I have an expensive operation that is repeated every iteration.

I have three `n`-dimensional vectors `x1`, `x2` and `x3` that are supposed to change every iteration.

I have four `N`-dimensional vectors `I1`, `I2`, `I3` and `v` that are pre-defined and will not change, where:

- `I1`, `I2` and `I3` contain the indices of respectively `x1`, `x2` and `x3` (the elements in `I_i` are between `0` and `n-1`)
- `v` is a vector of values.

For example:

[image]

We can see `v` as a (reshaped) **sparse** three-dimensional matrix, each index `k` of `v` corresponds to a triplet `(i1,i2,i3)` of indices of `x1`, `x2`, `x3`.

I want to compute at each iteration three `n`-dimensional vectors `y1`, `y2` and `y3` defined by:

```
y1[i1] = sum_{i2,i3} v(i1,i2,i3)*x2(i2)*x3(i3)

y2[i2] = sum_{i1,i3} v(i1,i2,i3)*x1(i1)*x3(i3)

y3[i3] = sum_{i1,i2} v(i1,i2,i3)*x1(i1)*x2(i2)
```

More precisely what the program does is:

> Repeat:
>
> - Compute `y1` then update `x1 = f(y1)`
> - Compute `y2` then update `x2 = f(y2)`
> - Compute `y3` then update `x3 = f(y3)`

where `f` is some external function.

I would like to know if there is a C++ library that helps me to do so as fast as possible. Using for loops is just too slow.

Thank you very much for your help!

**Update:** Looks like it's not easy to get a better solution than the straight-forward for loops. **If the vector of indices `I1` above is ordered in non-decreasing order, can we compute `y1` faster?**
For example: `I1 = [0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 ... n n]`.

Comment: A better place to ask for [software library recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is SoftwareRecs.StackExchange.com.

Comment: What order of magnitude are `n` and `N`? And if you just calculated, e.g., `temp[i1,i2]=sum_{i3} v(i1,i2,i3)*x3(i3)` how sparse would that intermediate result be? (this would be a sub-expression you could use for computing both `y2` and `y3`).

Comment: @chtz : Thanks. Approximately, N = 3e7 and n = 3e3. I haven't checked for the sparseness of `temp[i1,i2]`, but what will happen if it's very sparse or not quite sparse? I also tried to do this before asking the above question: compute and store `temp[i1,i2]` in a dense Eigen matrix at each iteration, then use it for computing both `y1` and `y2` using Eigen matrix multiplication. However, it's slower than my original solution (i.e. computing using straight-forward for loops for `yM`).

Comment: @chtz : In addition, if the vector of indices `I1` above is ordered in non-decreasing order, can we compute `y1` faster? Please see the update at the end of the question. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Assuming the indexes are distributed somewhat evenly, you have about 1e4 entries for each index of I1, I guess? And for each pair (i1, i2) you will have about 3 entries in V on average (so the result would be quite dense). If you already tried storing that into a dense matrix without success, it will not be worth it.

Comment: If entries in `I1` are sorted, you could try to store `v` in some sort of compressed-column format, i.e. don't store each `i1`, but just the start and end index of each block. When calculating `y1` accumulate `v(i1, i2, i3)*x2(i2)*x3(i3)` by first gathering all required elements into a dense (number of entries where `i1` is same)-sized array each and do a dense (and fast) elementwise product with summation afterwards. Is there some kind of symmetry how the indexes of `v` are distributed?

Comment: @chtz The indices of `I1` are not distributed evenly, unfortunately (I think I can make the numbers of each index equal by adding the missing indices with value v = 0). I have also been thinking of doing what you have suggested, i.e.: expanding `xM` according to `iM`, doing element-wise multiplication, and then doing a reduction/summation of the values of the same indices.

Comment: @chtz Oh yes thanks for asking about the symmetry. I have checked the data and it's actually symmetric: `v(i1,i2,i3) = v(j1,j2,j3)` where `(j1,j2,j3)` is any of the 6 permutations of `(i1,i2,i3)`, i.e. `v(i1,i2,i3) = v(i1,i3,i2) = v(i2,i3,i1) = v(i2,i1,i3) = v(i3,i1,i2) = v(i3,i2,i1)`. I think I could already get a significant speed-up even using for loops.

Comment: @chtz I was wrong, it's not that easy. Please see the update at the top of the question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, at least, not trivially. Your access pattern (e.g. `x2(i2)*x3(i3)`) does not (at least at compile time) access contiguous memory, but rather has a layer of indirection. Due to this, SIMD instructions are pretty useless, as they work on chunks of memory. What you may want to consider doing is creating a copy of `xM` sorted according to `iM`, removing the layer of indirection. This should reduce the number of cache misses in that `xM(iM)` generates and since it's accessed N times, that may reduce some of the wall time (assuming N is large).

If maximal accuracy is not critical, you may want to consider using a FFT method instead of the convolution (at least, that's how I understood your question. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Assuming you are doing a convolution and the vectors (`a` and `b`, same size as in your question) are large, the result (`c`) can be calculated naïvely as

```
// O(n^2)
for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    c(i) = a(i) * b.array();
```

Using the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), you could take the Fourier transform of both `a` and `b` and perform an element wise multiplication and then take the inverse Fourier transform of the result to get `c` (will probably differ a little):

```
// O(n log(n)); note A, B, and C are vectors of complex floating point numbers
fft.fwd(a, A);
fft.fwd(b, B);
C = A.array() * B.array();
fft.inv(C, c);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess that to minimize the cost, I have to iterate over `N` as few times as possible (if no vectorization is possible). Currently I only do that once for each `yM` (I cannot compute `y1`, `y2` and `y3` at once because I have to update `xM` in-between -- please see the updated question). So I cannot see how creating a copy of `xM`, as you have suggested, could improve the speed, because by creating them I already iterate over `N`? (Sorry I'm new to these kinds of things). 

And could you please give more details on how FFT can be applied to my case? It sounds very interesting.

Comment: Read e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384054/what-are-the-downsides-of-convolution-by-fft-compared-to-realspace-convolution). If I have time later, I may write up an example in my answer.

Comment: I don't think that FFT will help for this. The problem looks like a straight-forward (sparse) (Tensor*Vector)*Vector product to me. If you have AVX2 available this may even be partially vectorizable using gather instructions (which is not supported by Eigen, though).